# How to get assert to print a success message?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

Here is an assertion that I have written

```
assert.equal(0,0,"Test Passed);
```

I was hoping that it would print the message Test passed but it is not happening. However if the assertion fails the message is displayed along with the error.

So is there any way to print the message if the test is successful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the source, the message is only printed when the assertion fails.

```
assert.equal = function equal(actual, expected, message) {
  if (actual != expected) fail(actual, expected, message, '==', assert.equal);
};
```

Just for completeness here is the definition of `fail`.

```
function fail(actual, expected, message, operator, stackStartFunction) {
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
    message: message,
    actual: actual,
    expected: expected,
    operator: operator,
    stackStartFunction: stackStartFunction
  });
}
```

Comment: so.....  is there anyway to post a message if the test is successful?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in functionality to display a success message. However because `assert` throws an error (and execution stops) on failure, placing a success message immediately after the `assert` call effectively achieves the same thing:

```js
const assert = require('assert')

assert.deepStrictEqual(value, otherValue)
console.log('test passed') // unreachable if assert fails as it throws an error
```

`try/catch` can be used if you want execution to continue:

```js
const tests = [
  [0,1],
  [1,1],
]

for (const [value, otherValue] of tests) {
  try {
    assert.deepStrictEqual(value, otherValue)
    console.log(`Success: ${value} equals ${otherValue}`)
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(`Failure: ${value} does not equal ${otherValue}`)
  }
}

// output:
// Failure: 0 does not equal 1
// Success: 1 equals 1
```

Be aware that if this is used for automated testing the desired result on failure is probably still to either throw the error or `exit 1` to let the environment know that a test failed.